# error - WARNING: The version '1.9.4' of module 'Az.Accounts' is currently in use. Powershell script run on VM in Azure cloud

Tags: azure, powershell

Here is my powershell command sequence.

```
PS C:\Application01>Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope AllUsers

PS C:\Application01>Connect-AzAccount                  ### this prompts me for my azure logon

PS C:\Application01>Update-Module -Name Az

PS C:\Application01>.\Publish-Application01.ps1 -action "Deploy" `
                                        -azureAccountApplicationId "a3XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX76" `
                                        -azureAccountPassword "43XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXm" `
                                        -package "C:\Application01\Application01.server.Web.zip" `
                                        -azureSubscriptionId "c27XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX32" `
                                        -azureAccountTenantId "41XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1d" `
                                        -hostAdminPassword "XXXXXXXXXXXX" `
                                        -defaultTenantAdminPassword "XXXXXXXXXXX" `
                                        -resourceGroupName "RG01" `
                                        -appServiceName "Applicationservice01" `
                                        -nugetRepositoryType "Composite" `
                                        -storageType "Azure" ` 
                                        -storageLocation "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https://XXXXXXXXX" `
                                        -appSettings  @{"Telemetry.Enabled"="false"} `
                                        -verbose

WARNING: The version '1.9.4' of module 'Az.Accounts' is currently in use. Retry the operation after closing the applications.
WARNING: The provided service principal secret will be included in the 'AzureRmContext.json' file found in the user profile ( C:\Users\zzadmin\.Azure ). Please ensure that this directory has appropriate protections.
Connect-AzAccount : The provided account a3XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX76 does not have access to subscription ID "c2XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2". Please try logging in with different credentials or a different subscription ID.
At C:\Application01\Publish-Application01.ps1:577 char:9
+     if (Connect-AzAccount -Environment AzureUSGovernment -ServicePrin ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX


Line 577 >>> -ServicePrincipal  --
```

my understanding is a prompt will appear to enter a value for ServicePrincipal.

Here is the azure Function.

```
function AuthenticateToAzure {

    $securePassword = $azureAccountPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAccountApplicationId, $securePassword)

    if (Connect-AzAccount -Environment AzureUSGovernment -ServicePrincipal -SubscriptionId $azureSubscriptionId -TenantId $azureAccountTenantId -Credential $credential){
        Write-Host "Logged in to Az" -ForegroundColor Green
    } else {
        Write-Error "Failed to log in to Az"
        Exit 1
    }

XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I have tried rebooting the VM and error still appears.

The zzadmin account on the VM is a local administrator.

User account logon Azure is the owner role.

Comment: Have you checked the AzureRM Module? There is a conflict with AzureRM module and AzureAz module.